# Why does the runtime shows the generic types as "GenericType`n"?

Tags: .net, generics, reflection, types

And why doesn't it shows the real type (eg: List<string> instead of List`1)?
Where does this strange (to me) notation comes from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `1 is MSIL syntax for a generic type - `List<T>` is C#-specific. More MSIL examples:

```
List<T> == System.Collections.Generic.List`1
```

```
List<string> == System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

```
Dictionary<string, int> == 
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String, System.Int32]
```

Comment: I think you missed the point. \`1 doesn't define a generic class for the CLR. At the IL level, a generic class can be arbitrarily named. It's a method to resolve ambiguities between overloaded generic types for higher level languages. It declares the number of type parameters for the type so that you can overload types by the number of generic parameters. Your example is wrong. `Dictionary<string, int>` is Dictionary\`2[System.String,System.Int32], not Dictionary\`1, since it has **two** type parameters.

Answer (score 9):

The CLR name for generic `List<T>` with one type parameter is

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1
```

`List<T>` is the C# style of naming that type.

The notation is a convention defined to give you the ability to overload generic types by parameter count. If you declare a class named `List` with two type parameters (e.g. `List<T,U>`) the compiler would be able to choose the right one. It'll be named:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`2
```

and a non-generic `List` class will be named:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List
```

Note that the CLR does not *require* generic types to be named like that. It's just a convention for the compilers to be able to pick the right type.

Comment: I thought the CLI didn't erase generic types? If not, where does "String" when "List<String>" becomes List`1?

Comment: `List<T>` becomes List\`1. It's the "open generic type definition." The closed definition of `List<string>` will become List\`1[System.String].

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't show `List<string>` because that's C# dependent syntax.  A List in .Net source code could be declared as `List<string>`, `List(Of String)` or any of the other 60 or so languages/syntaxes that can compile down to MSIL.

So what you're seeing is the more generic MSIL syntax.

The `1 means that it is a List that has one generic parameter.