# Getting Class FullName (including namespace) from Roslyn ClassDeclarationSyntax

Tags: c#, roslyn

I've a ClassDeclarationSyntax from a syntax tree in roslyn.
I read it like this:

```
var tree = SyntaxTree.ParseText(sourceCode);
var root = (CompilationUnitSyntax)tree.GetRoot();

var classes = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>();
```

The identifier only contains the name of the class but no information about the namespace, so the fullType Name is missing. Like "MyClass" but noch "Namespace1.MyClass"

what is the recommended way to get the namespace / FulltypeName of the  Syntax?

Comment: AFAIK, that information comes from the semantic tree.

Comment: I fear your right with your information i found: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bbb8c695-7555-4d27-b6ef-442f3f0492a5/getting-fulltypename-from-classdeclarationsyntax  But that seems ugly to me. and in my scenario if feat it would cost a lot of performacne :-(

Comment: As mentioned there, you could build it yourself by recursively finding namespace declarations.  Beware of nested generic classes.

Comment: I overread the solution by dfinding it recursively. In my scenario I can exclude nested generic classes. Many thanks.

Comment: ...use semantics, it's really the correct approach. In VB.NET code at least, any attempt to determine it syntactically is broken in common scenarios.

Answer (score 9):

you can do this using the helper class I wrote:

```
NamespaceDeclarationSyntax namespaceDeclarationSyntax = null;
if (!SyntaxNodeHelper.TryGetParentSyntax(classDeclarationSyntax, out namespaceDeclarationSyntax))
{
    return; // or whatever you want to do in this scenario
}

var namespaceName = namespaceDeclarationSyntax.Name.ToString();
var fullClassName = namespaceName + "." + classDeclarationSyntax.Identifier.ToString();
```

and the helper:

```
static class SyntaxNodeHelper
{
    public static bool TryGetParentSyntax<T>(SyntaxNode syntaxNode, out T result) 
        where T : SyntaxNode
    {
        // set defaults
        result = null;

        if (syntaxNode == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            syntaxNode = syntaxNode.Parent;

            if (syntaxNode == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (syntaxNode.GetType() == typeof (T))
            {
                result = syntaxNode as T;
                return true;
            }

            return TryGetParentSyntax<T>(syntaxNode, out result);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

There is nothing overly complex going on here... it makes sense that the namespace would be "up" the syntax tree (because the class is contained within the namespace) so you simply need to travel "up" the syntax tree until you find the namespace and append that to the identifier of the `ClassDeclarationSyntax`.

Comment: why don't you just var namespace = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<NamespaceDeclarationSyntax>();

Comment: not sure if this works now, but I think this wasn't supported at the time - it's been a while since I've worked with Roslyn

Comment: When I tried to use this in a scenario with nested classes I realised that all nesting classes are omtted with this approach.

`namespace MyNsmespace 
{
  class MyOuterClass
  {
    public class MyInnerClass
    {
        // ...
    }
  }
}
`
should resolve to `MyNamespace.MyOuterClass+MyInnerClass`

Comment: @johnny5 I think `DescendantNodes` is the wrong direction in the syntax tree as it goes down instead of up. I solved it by using `syntaxNode.Ancestors().OfType<NamespaceDeclarationSyntax>();`

Comment: hmm the op is looking for descendents, however you can walk either way for your solution

Answer (score 6):

Build an `ITypeSymbol` for your class definition.

Then get its "full qualified name"

```
ClassDeclarationSyntax myclass; //your class here

var typeSymbol = context.Compilation.GetSemanticModel(myclass.SyntaxTree).GetDeclaredSymbol(myclass);

typeSymbol.ToDisplayString(SymbolDisplayFormat.FullyQualifiedFormat);
//-------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^this
```

Comment: ingenious. i think this is the best solution. it also adds the "global::" prefix.

Answer (score 5):

There's also an elegant way when using pattern matching + recursion:

```cs
// method with pattern matching
public static string GetNamespaceFrom(SyntaxNode s) =>
    s.Parent switch
    {
        NamespaceDeclarationSyntax namespaceDeclarationSyntax => namespaceDeclarationSyntax.Name.ToString(),
        null => string.Empty, // or whatever you want to do
        _ => GetNamespaceFrom(s.Parent)
    };

// somewhere call it passing the class declaration syntax:
string ns = GetNamespaceFrom(classDeclarationSyntax);
```

Comment: Looks like this doesn't support namespaces without curly brace ala .net 6

Comment: @josedbaez This can easily be fixed by replacing `NamespaceDeclarationSyntax` with `BaseNamespaceDeclarationSyntax`

Answer (score 2):

I know I am rather late in the game, but I stumbled upon [one of given the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23249021/3881834) which did not work in my case where I had to deal with nested classes. So therefore here is a method that will handle nested classes as well:

```
public static class ClassDeclarationSyntaxExtensions
{
    public const string NESTED_CLASS_DELIMITER = "+";
    public const string NAMESPACE_CLASS_DELIMITER = ".";

    public static string GetFullName(this ClassDeclarationSyntax source)
    {
        Contract.Requires(null != source);

        var items = new List<string>();
        var parent = source.Parent;
        while (parent.IsKind(SyntaxKind.ClassDeclaration))
        {
            var parentClass = parent as ClassDeclarationSyntax;
            Contract.Assert(null != parentClass);
            items.Add(parentClass.Identifier.Text);

            parent = parent.Parent;
        }

        var nameSpace = parent as NamespaceDeclarationSyntax;
        Contract.Assert(null != nameSpace);
        var sb = new StringBuilder().Append(nameSpace.Name).Append(NAMESPACE_CLASS_DELIMITER);
        items.Reverse();
        items.ForEach(i => { sb.Append(i).Append(NESTED_CLASS_DELIMITER); });
        sb.Append(source.Identifier.Text);

        var result = sb.ToString();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [the answer by Ronald](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52694992/861773), I added support for: nested namespaces, structs and generics.

It uses the [generics CLR naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1482164/861773) to allow the output to be used as input of [Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.compilation.gettypebymetadataname)

```
public static class TypeDeclarationSyntaxExtensions
{
    const char NESTED_CLASS_DELIMITER = '+';
    const char NAMESPACE_CLASS_DELIMITER = '.';
    const char TYPEPARAMETER_CLASS_DELIMITER = '`';

    public static string GetFullName(this TypeDeclarationSyntax source)
    {
        if (source is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

        var namespaces = new LinkedList<BaseNamespaceDeclarationSyntax>();
        var types = new LinkedList<TypeDeclarationSyntax>();
        for (var parent = source.Parent; parent is object; parent = parent.Parent)
        {
            if (parent is BaseNamespaceDeclarationSyntax @namespace)
            {
                namespaces.AddFirst(@namespace);
            }
            else if (parent is TypeDeclarationSyntax type)
            {
                types.AddFirst(type);
            }
        }

        var result = new StringBuilder();
        for (var item = namespaces.First; item is object; item = item.Next)
        {
            result.Append(item.Value.Name).Append(NAMESPACE_CLASS_DELIMITER);
        }
        for (var item = types.First; item is object; item = item.Next)
        {
            var type = item.Value;
            AppendName(result, type);
            result.Append(NESTED_CLASS_DELIMITER);
        }
        AppendName(result, source);

        return result.ToString();
    }

    static void AppendName(StringBuilder builder, TypeDeclarationSyntax type)
    {
        builder.Append(type.Identifier.Text);
        var typeArguments = type.TypeParameterList?.ChildNodes()
            .Count(node => node is TypeParameterSyntax) ?? 0;
        if (typeArguments != 0)
            builder.Append(TYPEPARAMETER_CLASS_DELIMITER).Append(typeArguments);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
public static string GetFullName(NamespaceDeclarationSyntax node)
{
    if (node.Parent is NamespaceDeclarationSyntax)
        return String.Format("{0}.{1}",
            GetFullName((NamespaceDeclarationSyntax)node.Parent),
            ((IdentifierNameSyntax)node.Name).Identifier.ToString());
    else
        return ((IdentifierNameSyntax)node.Name).Identifier.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Why are you taking in a NamespaceDeclarationSyntax and not just a syntaxnode

Comment: It is a part of CSharpSyntaxWalker descendant with owerriden VisitNamespaceDeclaration(NamespaceDeclarationSyntax node).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I get the namespace. You have to slightly modify my code for your case:

```
        public static async Task<NamespaceDeclarationSyntax> GetNamespaceAsync(this Document document, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            SyntaxNode documentRoot = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            var rootCompUnit = (CompilationUnitSyntax)documentRoot;
            return (NamespaceDeclarationSyntax)rootCompUnit.Members.Where(m => m.IsKind(SyntaxKind.NamespaceDeclaration)).Single();
        }
```

Comment: I think this is only half of the story. What if the namespaces are nested? I would recommend going up until you reached the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another answer.. This utility class supports nested namespaces and nested classes as well.

```cs
public static class SyntaxNodeHelper
{
    public static string GetPrefix(SyntaxNode member)
    {
        if (member == null) {
            return "";
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        SyntaxNode node = member;

        while(node.Parent != null) {
            node = node.Parent;

            if (node is NamespaceDeclarationSyntax) {
                var namespaceDeclaration = (NamespaceDeclarationSyntax) node;

                sb.Insert(0, ".");
                sb.Insert(0, namespaceDeclaration.Name.ToString());
            } else if (node is ClassDeclarationSyntax) {
                var classDeclaration = (ClassDeclarationSyntax) node;

                sb.Insert(0, ".");
                sb.Insert(0, classDeclaration.Identifier.ToString());
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code could solve your problem.

```cs
public static string ClassFullName(this ClassDeclarationSyntax varClassDec)
{
    SyntaxNode tempCurCls = varClassDec;
    var tempFullName = new Stack<string>();
    
    do
    {
        if (tempCurCls.Kind() == SyntaxKind.ClassDeclaration)
        {
            tempFullName.Push(((ClassDeclarationSyntax)tempCurCls).Identifier.ToString());
        }
        else if (tempCurCls.Kind() == SyntaxKind.NamespaceDeclaration)
        {
            tempFullName.Push(((NamespaceDeclarationSyntax)tempCurCls).Name.ToString());
        }
        
        tempCurCls = tempCurCls.Parent;
    } while (tempCurCls != null);
    
    return string.Join(".", tempFullName);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Lock have made a awesome blog post regarding (incremental) source generators. He describe how you can find the namespace for a class syntax taking into account file scope namespaces, nested namespaces and no namespace at all.

Check it out
https://andrewlock.net/creating-a-source-generator-part-5-finding-a-type-declarations-namespace-and-type-hierarchy/#finding-the-namespace-for-a-class-syntax

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use:

```
public static class SyntaxNodeExtensions
{
    public static string? GetNamespace(this SyntaxNode syntaxNode)
    {
        return string.Join(".", syntaxNode
                .Ancestors()
                .OfType<BaseNamespaceDeclarationSyntax>()
                .Reverse()
                .Select(_ => _.Name)
            );
    }
}
```

And example usage:

```
void Main()
{
    string code = @"
    namespace NoBrackets;
    
    namespace A
    {
        namespace B
        {
            namespace NoBrackets2;
            
            namespace C
            {
                public class Blah() { }
            }
        }
    }
    ";
    var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);
    var root = tree.GetRoot();
    var cl = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().Single();
    var ns = cl.GetNamespace();
    Console.WriteLine(ns);
}
```

Output is:

`NoBrackets.A.B.NoBrackets2.C`