# Getting namespace of class

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

[image]can you please help me to find out the namespace from **VariableDeclarationSyntax**, **StatementSyntax** and **IdentifierNameSyntax** ?

I am just using the below code, but it always replies the "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax" namespace only.

**string namespaceName = identifierSyntax.GetType().BaseType.Namespace;**

Please consider the below example:

```
Package X;

Class A {};

Class B
{
A a;
}
```

Here both classes are available in the package X; So i don't want to refer the namespace of class A in B, if i'm using the A's instance in B class.
But i want the namespace name of Class A 
using Roslyn. is there any way to get it?

Comment: I think that the real issue is that when you call GetType() that is the "GetType" method that exists on the base .net Object type - it's not one of the Roslyn methods (it's returning the type of the actual node reference, rather than the type in the code being analysed that the node describes). Hopefully the second part of my (revised) answer illustrates how to get the type that you're interested in.

Comment: is there any way to get those names by using SyntaxNode?

Comment: You need the semantic model.

Comment: Are you happy that my answer addresses your original question? Is there anything additional that you would like in order for you to accept it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40612165/1498252

Answer (score 1):

From an IdentifierNameSyntax, if you want to determine what namespace that identifier is declared within then you may do the following (and so you'll be able to do the same from other node types) -

```
var ns = context.Node.Ancestors().OfType<NamespaceDeclarationSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that this will sometimes be null. For example, if you are analysing the following content

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class TypeName
    {   
    }
}
```

Then "System", "Collections", "Generic", etc.. will result in instances of IdentifierNameSyntax but they are not within a namespace.

Alternaitvely, if you have a VariableDeclarationSyntax and you want to know what namespace contains the type that the variable is of, then you can do this:

```
var variableDeclaration = (VariableDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;
var type = context.SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(variableDeclaration.Type).Type;
if ((type != null) && !(type is IErrorTypeSymbol)) // This will happen if the type lookup fails
{
    var ns = type.ContainingNamespace;
}
```

If you were analysing the line

```
var x = new SqlCommand();
```

then "type" would be "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand" and so "ns" would be the namespace "System.Data.SqlClient";

Comment: It only returns the namespaces that used in the current file. I need to access the  namespaces that are not written in the file.

Comment: Sorry, did you mean that you want to know what namespaces are referenced by the code, rather than which are defined in the code? So, if there was a line "var command = new SqlCommand();" then you want to know that SqlCommand is from the "System.Data" namespace?

Comment: Question modified. Please refer it @Dan Roberts

Comment: is there any way to get those names by using SyntaxNode?

Comment: I don't believe that there is - it couldn't be reliable, even if there was, as there are so many scenarios where the type would be declared elsewhere in the model and so not in the syntax tree from the source code that you are currently considering. Before resorting to this more expensive method, I suppose that you could identify all namespaces and all types that ARE in the current syntax tree and then see if any of them match? (Even then, it only works when the type is clear - I think that resolving "var" definitely requires SemanticModel access).

Answer (score 0):

you can use semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(identifierNameSyntax) which returns a SymbolInfo. SymbolInfo.Symbol is an ISymbol, so you can use ISymbol.ContainingNamespace to get the namespace an identifier belongs to.

var namespace = $"{semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(identifierNameSyntax).Symbol.ContainingNamespace}";