# Roslyn's GetTypeByMetadataName() and Generic Types

Tags: c#, types, roslyn

I'm trying to retrieve all the IMethodSymbols within a given type. For closed types (ie. types without generics) I can just use [CSharpCompilation.GetTypeByMetaDataName()](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Compilation/Compilation.cs#b69619b653a39389) and pass in the fully qualified type name.

However, with an open type (eg. `MyClass<T>`) the fully qualified name doesn't seem to work. I've tried supplying the fully qualified name without the type parameter (`MyClass`), and also with a closed type (`MyClass<int>`), but neither seems to work.

What's the best way to find this type using its fully qualified name?

Comment: I'd have thought it would be MyClass`1.

Comment: I suspect the standard naming pattern for generic types applies: `MyClass\`1`

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1483451/736079

Comment: You guys are correct, appending `1 correctly retrieves the type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the compiler convention is to take a class name like `MyClass<T>` and represent it as

```
MyClass`1
```

A working example:

```
var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
public class MyClass<T> {
    public static T Method()
    {
    }
}");

var mscorlib = new MetadataFileReference(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("MyCompilation",
       syntaxTrees: new[] { tree }, references: new[] { mscorlib });

var type = compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("MyClass`1");
```